# Tag links in tag excerpts not shown properly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt, tag-links

If a tag excerpt contains a link to another tag with the `[tag:foobar]` syntax, this link is not properly shown in every context. For an example see [this list of tagged questions](http://libraries.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-libraries). The link is shown as `[tag:school-libraries]` but it should be [school-libraries](/questions/tagged/school-libraries) or at least "school-libraries".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help text when editing a tag wiki:

> The tag wiki excerpt is a brief **plain text** introduction to the topic that the tag represents.

Emphasis is mine; the wiki excerpt is explicitly plain text only and no formatting *at all* is supported, let alone tag links. Thus, in this case I'm inclined to call this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

See the original [blog post announcing the feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) as well:

> **The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag**. You only have ~500 plain text characters for the excerpt, so don’t feel obligated to cover everything in it!

The markup for the tag should be removed from that excerpt altogether.

Comment: Yup, all correct...I've cleaned up that excerpt to take care of this instance.

Comment: I don't like that its supposed to be plaintext. Makes no sense to me. Especially for sub-tags like the [tag:debian-squeeze] is for [tag:debian].

Comment: @aef: The text is used in popups all over the site, that have both limited space and very strict styling requirements. Plain text means no styling. Use the full tag wiki for that.

Comment: Could we at least have bold/italics? They would be useful for avoiding all caps in messages like "such and such tag is about so and so. PLEASE DON'T USE THIS TAG FOR THIS OR THAT".

Comment: @gandalf3: You are assuming that people actually read the tags. Bold and italics is not going to help here; people either read the tag description, or more often, ignore the description altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unfortunately your probably right, but it's shown when the user is selecting a tag, so maybe bold text might get their attention then.

Comment: The help text no longer has mention of "plain text".