# Allow hyperlinks in tag wiki excerpts

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, tag-wiki-excerpt

Hyperlinks (and any other formatting) don't work in tag wiki excerpts. This is a shame, because they would be helpful.

Right now if you read a tag wiki excerpt you have to click through the tag wiki proper to use the hyperlinks which is tedious.

eg. [image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequel

Comment: Pretty sure that's by design. The excerpt is meant for display in tooltips and the autocomplete, where links or formatting would be disruptive.

Comment: Well, the excerpt felt a little too promotional for my taste.  Have a look at my edit.  Users can always click the `info` link in the excerpt dropdown (or the `learn more` link in the faq page header) if they want more detail.

Comment: Related counter-request: [Block hyperlinks in tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208187/block-hyperlinks-in-tag-wiki-excerpts)

Answer (score 6):

Tag wiki excerpts are for [quick plain text descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138023/tag-links-in-tag-excerpts-not-shown-properly) for:

- when the tag should be added to a question
- what other tag might be better, or
- a cursory note on what it represents.

When it starts to become a launch pad for other sites or pages to check out, it's time to dial it back.

Adding in the ability to format, link or imageificate the excerpt veers it into a canyon of oil slicked souls and renders it more promotional than information purposed for the community.

The rest of the tag wiki is open slather for links and other resources. A better place to grasp the sides of and pull it apart to allow better putting one's head up the tag's world of understanding and learning.

Comment: One more case: when other _site_ might be better (with a link to the site). Example: "video" tag on photo.stackexchange.com.