# Block hyperlinks in tag wiki excerpts

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, tag-wiki-excerpt

Tag wiki excerpts are plain text, they allow no formatting whatsoever. In particular, there are no hyperlinks in tag wiki excerpts.

Including a hyperlink in a tag wiki excerpt is a common mistake. It would be easy to block them server-side.

If a suggested edit or direct edit for a tag wiki excerpt includes the substring `http://` or `https://`, please reject it outright, with a clear message (something like “Hyperlinks and other formatting are not supported in tag wiki excerpts.”).

(The tag wiki excerpts for `url` and `http` on SO and SU don't include any hyperlink, so I think it's safe to say that no excerpt needs to include text that happens to look like a hyperlink.)

This could be generalized to other attempts at formatting, but the risk of false positives may be too high.

Comment: Isn't that why tag-wiki edit is given to trusted users only and otherwise the users have to pass through a review queue?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Even if reviewers were perfect, their time shouldn't be wasted rejecting edits that are obviously wrong. In practice, not only are reviewers *ahem* imperfect, but it's easy to miss in the review queue that you're dealing with an excerpt rather than a body — I know it's happened to me several times, and I'm an experienced and conscientious reviewer.

Comment: Related counter-request: [Allow hyperlinks in tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156297/allow-hyperlinks-in-tag-wiki-excerpts)

Answer (score 2):

While not particularly common, there are some scenarios where it makes sense to include a URL in a tag excerpt. For example, take the following Super User tags.

[Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/tags/ubuntu/info)

> Free, open-source operating system based on Debian GNU/Linux. Ubuntu
> questions are on topic here, but if you prefer an Ubuntu-only audience
> there is [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

[Google-docs](https://superuser.com/tags/google-docs/info)

> Better asked at [WebApps.StackExchange.com](https://WebApps.StackExchange.com) unless specifically
> involving your computer setup.

[Microsoft-outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook)

> Email client, calendar/appointment manager and address book/contacts
> list software. Not to be confused with [outlook.com](http://outlook.com), the new
> name/interface for Hotmail.

There may be an argument for restricting the use of `http://` or `https://`, but I think these examples show why hyperlinks shouldn't be blocked altogether.

Comment: That's an argument for rendering hyperlinks. But right now the hyperlinks are not rendered, they're just shown as a string of characters like any other text. So you see e.g. `Ask Ubuntu (http://askubuntu.com/)` and `confused with outlook.com`, and these are *not* hyperlinks.

Comment: @Gilles If we were specifically blocking hyperlinks, I suppose `http://askubuntu.com` could be changed to `askubuntu.com`

Comment: Just a note:  SE uses network-wide HTTPS, so I made the appropriate changes.