# Long words in tag excerpts move outside the box

Tags: bug, design, tag-wiki-excerpt, popups

When there's an extremely long 'word', like a link, the tag excerpt popup does not hyphenate the word and break it to a new line. Instead, it extends outwards, like so:

[image]
(link to [that particular revision history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/455755/revisions), though it's observable everywhere that popup is supposed to appear)

I'm aware that tag excerpts are generally not formatted and [this well-recieved meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208187) even tries to make a case for banning hyperlinks in tag excerpts, but I do think it's rather useful to be able to put links anyways. On Physics at least, we have a few tags which have links to meta posts for guidance regarding certain kinds of questions.

I'm on Chrome 71.0.3578.98  for Windows 10; I could reproduce this on Edge and Vivaldi too.

Comment: [Works fine in FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwtLB.png)

Comment: Meta.SO cross-site post: [Tag popup text overflows due to URL addresses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379048/4642212).