# Warn tag wiki excerpt creators/editors that markup/links don't work in excerpts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, markdown, tag-wiki-excerpt

I ran across another tag wiki excerpt suggested edit that had put markdown for a hyperlink in the excerpt (actually it already had them, it just modified it). So I rejected the edit, then waited until it was approved and then edited it out.

With suggested edits possible at low levels, it might be nice to warn any user who makes a tag wiki excerpt edit (or creates one) that hyperlinks don't work, triggered by link markdown being used.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208187/block-hyperlinks-in-tag-wiki-excerpts

Comment: Certainly, if it must be so. But must it be so? And if so, why?

Comment: @RegEdit, that's already been a topic of other questions, like this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156300/13295

Comment: Hmmmph. And presumably it's not possible that abusing markup in a _question_ or _answer_ also "veers _it_ into a canyon of oil slicked souls and renders it more promotional than information purposed for the community"?

Comment: The reason I'm pressing the question here rather than elsewhere is that I think it makes sense to allow markup, at least to some degree, in which case it would be better not to reinforce the status quo by adding the warning message. The obvious example where it would be useful being references to related tags. For instance, the exceprt for [tag:design] would then be able to say, "For questions about database structure, algorithms in the code, please use [tag:database-design] instead", thereby enjoying the same increased readability that the mechanism provides everywhere else.

Comment: i agree that markdown, especially links should be allow in excerpts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Adam made this happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254665/tell-people-that-tag-excerpts-do-not-support-formatting/350727#350727):

> [image: Plain text only, no Markdown formatting]

Answer (score 7):

Yes! We must implement this now.

There should be a error box that says:

> Hyperlinks cannot be used in tag wiki excerpts.

when the system detects a hyperlink in the tag wiki edit. Also, on the right side where it shows you how to edit and improve tag wikis:

[image]

There should be an additional sentence in the "Tag Wiki Excerpt" section where it says that you cannot use hyperlink in the excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

*Turning this into an answer, after some positive response to my comment.*

Well... yes and no.

In fact, no.

I've read [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156297/hyperlinks-in-tag-wiki-excerpts/156300#156300) that putting markup in a tag is  evil and  "veers it into a canyon of oil slicked souls and renders it more promotional than information purposed for the community". Hmm. Presumably it's not possible that abusing markup in a *question* or *answer* would be evil also?

Instead of displaying this warning, we should allow markup, at least to some degree. The obvious example where it would be useful being references to related tags. For instance, the excerpt for [design](/questions/tagged/design) would then be able to say

> For questions about database structure, algorithms in the code, please
>   use [database-design](/questions/tagged/database-design) instead.

thereby enjoying the same increased readability and compactness that the mechanism provides everywhere else.

Comment: So in the very small format of a tooltip, which is what the tag wiki excerpts are used for, how do you think the tag format would fit in?

Comment: @Lance I would say [the same way it fits in in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). That's to say, tag markdown along the lines of 'please use [ tag:database-design ] instead' is rendered 'please use [tag:database-design] instead'. In the context of a tag wiki excerpt, this is clearly superior to 'please use the "database-design" tag instead': its special rendering makes it stand out as a special entity in the sentence, obviating the need for quotes or the extra words "the" and "tag"...

Comment: ...thereby improving compactness (important in the limited space available in a tag wiki excerpt) and also improving legibility. Meanwhile the link, if used, leads the user to the question list for the cited tag, thereby showing examples of its usage, headed by the link to the tag wiki  for full information about the tag.