# Warning about no markdown in tag excerpts missing

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, markdown, tag-wiki-excerpt

The [warning about markdown doesn't work in tag excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259246/warn-tag-wiki-excerpt-creators-editors-that-markup-links-dont-work-in-excerpts) seems to be missing when editing an excerpt from the suggested edits review queue (by pressing "improve edit").

Another place it doesn't appear is when editing a revision of an excerpt:

[image]

as can be seen, the warning doesn't appear (if you don't believe me then [feel free to see for yourself](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/posts/3496/revisions) (by clicking "edit" on the last revision...)).

So, I'm guessing this is really a tiny bug, but might as well.