# Help text for Tag wiki excerpts does not mention markdown is not supported

Tags: bug, markdown, wording, tag-wiki-excerpt

Is markdown allowed for tag wiki excerpts?

For example, can I do for [goatse](/questions/tagged/goatse)

```
An operator used in [tag:perl]
```

When [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/51) a tag, I was given a link to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/ but no technical information.

The description of a tag wiki excerpt given is

> The usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

Unlike in the version of the help text mentioned in the accepted answer of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138024/38765 , there's no information that the excerpt is "plain text".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag links in tag excerpts not shown properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138023/tag-links-in-tag-excerpts-not-shown-properly)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks for that, but the help text I received is different from that mentioned in the accepted answer of the question you link to.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess they have changed that text fairly recently, though they still don't render Markdown in tag wiki excerpts. I wonder why it's been changed to be less clear.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: The text quoted in the second section of the answer is the same as can still be found in the blog post you linked.

Comment: They changed the text and forgot to explain it's plain text only, so I consider this a bug in wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [June 14th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350727/4751173) (thanks @Pang), when you edit a tag wiki excerpt, you are reminded that tag wiki excerpts are

> (plain text only, no Markdown formatting)

---

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350727

Answer (score 4):

In tag excerpts, no markdown is allowed. Not even `[tag:another-tag]` markdown is allowed:

[image]

It is only allowed in tag wikis:

[image]

This is because the tag excerpt is a short description of the tag.

A tag wiki is a full wiki about the tag, so markdown is allowed.

Comment: Go ahead and fix [tag:minecraft]

Comment: True, but that's not the point here, as the help text does not mention this anymore.